# .htaccess pretty urls

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to make my URLs pretty with htaccess.

I have only one variable `id`. So the pages are like `index.php?id=1`, `index.php?id=2` etc.
What I would like them to be is something like `index/1/`, `index/2/` - like folders, instead of the `id` variable...

How can I accomplish that using htaccess rewrite URLs?

I was trying to do it like that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?id=$1[L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yours seems to be working ... is there any error? Maybe change to `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ index.php?id=$1 [L]` (add `/$` to the end of the rule, add a space before `[L]`)

Comment: It gives me Object not found, 404 error... and your tip does not change it...

Comment: Try `/index.php` instead of `index.php`. When your use `/1/` it is not looking in your www-root path but in the /1/ path. See in your apache error.log to get more details about errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

if the index.php file is something like this:

```
<?php
import_request_variables('g', 'req_');
var_dump($req_id);
```

and you make a request to http://domain/1

then index.php has the variable req_id=1 (because of the import_request_variables call)