# Htaccess to make "pretty" URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make pretty URLs, but it doesn't seems do anything. This is my first attempt and I'm trying to do this according to a guide, so I think I'm missing something or it's not that simple. Maybe someone can help? Any advice? I tried to do this with a generator but none of them generated code that would works.

For your reference, this is the current URL format: **domain.com/articles.php?page=1**

I am trying to turn that into this: **domain.com/articles/page/1/**

This is what i have written inside .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule    ^articles/([0-9]+)/?$    articles.php?page=$1    [NC,L]
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: If you url always will contain the `page` part you won't need a specific regex for picking up that part, you simply use a rule like: `RewriteRule ^articles/page/([0-9]+)/$ articles.php?page=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess pretty urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874596/htaccess-pretty-urls)

Answer (score 3):

For this pretty URL: `domain.com/articles/page/1/`:

Your regex seems to be wrong. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^articles/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$  articles.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Why just not simply use ^articles/page/([0-9]+)/$ articles.php?page=$1 [NC,L] instead?

Comment: Yes that is also possible, I just wasn't sure if page is not a dynamic text.

Comment: Nothing :(. URL is still same. Atleast now i know i got right regex and i cant start looking problem somewhere else

Comment: If you want URL to change also then use `R` flag as: `RewriteRule ^articles/[^/]+/([0-9]+)/?$  articles.php?page=$1 [NC,L,R]`

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser? And what is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: I go to index page (domain.com). There i press link that leads me to- domain.com/articles.php?page=1. .htaccess is in same folder as articles.php and index.php. They all are in my hosting service root directory public_html/.

Comment: Enter this URL in your browser: `http://domain.com/articles/page/1/` and tell me what happens?

Comment: wait, i was wrong...when i paste this: http://domain.com/articles/page/1/ it changes to this domain.com/articles.php?page=1 and everything looks fine. But when i paste this domain.com/articles/page/1/ i get right page but without CSS

Comment: Correct that is because you're using relative URIs for CSS/JS etc.  You can try adding this in your page's header: `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 2):

some time ago i wrote the one below, the pros are:

- you store controller and actions like in zend
- you can have as much parameters as you like
- you can store css, js and images in folder /public/

code in .httacess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?public/.+$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&params=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)?(.*)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2&%1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?controller=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

the contr is that in your bootstrap (index.html) you must add this at the begining:

```
/*
 * Split params from given URL
 */
$_PARAMS = array();
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $_PARAMS[$key] = $value;
}

if (isset($_GET['params'])) {
        $_TEMP = explode( ",", $_GET['params'] );
        for ($i = 0; $i+1 < count($_TEMP) ; $i+=2) {
                $_PARAMS[$_TEMP[$i]] = $_TEMP[$i+1];
        }

}

$controller = "";
$action = "";
/*
 * load controller -> layout -> action
 */
$controller = isset($_GET['controller']) ? $_GET['controller'] : "";
$action = isset($_GET['action']) ? $_GET['action'] : "index";
```

and you get params from $_PARAMS