# Rewrite GET variables php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make a rewrite,and my script is like this :

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
if($id) {
echo "Your id are $id";
} else {
echo "Id are missing";
}
?>
```

with `.htaccess` i want to make it in my url like this : `http://example.com/something/id`

So,what must i `edit` in my `php` and add to my `.htaccess` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess pretty urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6874596/htaccess-pretty-urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the variable values automaticly by this method

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteEngine On Options All -Indexes RewriteBase /directoryname/ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    ###############  SEO     ##########################

#
http://www.example.com/hello/booboo/ it takes the url  after .com/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ getme.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

for example if i enter http://www.example.com/hello/bobo/

it is going to replace and take "/hello/bobo/" part now you can use this in .htacces file Also if you want to redirect to another page and filter the variable value you should modify $1 because all data in this.

edit: in that example i get url after my domain and i redirect to get.php also you can divide the url using split method by "/" Let's see the get.php page to understand this method

getme.php:

```
<?php

//we redirect to get in url=$1 so our get method name is url
$parca = explode("/", $_GET["url"]); //and we divided by slash the url.

echo $parca[0];//this is first part "/hello/
echo $parca[1];// and this is second part "/booboo/;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you :) i'm understand

Answer (score 3):

Try the following in Root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /file.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Replace /file.php with your  file .

This will internally redirect

```
example.com/123
```

to

```
example.com/file.php?id=123
```

Comment: so if my file is `/something/index.php`

`file.php` replace to `index.php`?

Comment: If the target path is /something/index.php , then you can replace file.php with /something/index.php