# How to solve .htaccess get variable in php issue?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, get

This is my code for pages.php but it gives me **500 Internal Server Error** in wamp server for my all cms files. On the other hand, if i remove this .htaccess file, cms works fine. But i want a beautiful url for get variables. **HELP PLSEASE**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^page_id/(\w+)$./pages.php?id=$1
```

Get variable in php

```
$page_id = $_GET["id"];
```

Comment: Where is your PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate Question]

Please check below link :

[.htaccess rewrite GET variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677070/htaccess-rewrite-get-variables)

[Rewrite GET variables php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34240574/rewrite-get-variables-php)

[Access GET variables with PHP + .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375680/access-get-variables-with-php-htaccess)